# jQuery Validation plugin messages on file items don't clear after picking a legal file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate some forms.  I have a file field in the form, for which I have an entry in the `rules` clause something like `the_file: { required: true, accept: 'txt|doc' }`. This successfully detects the absence of a selected file or the selection of a file with the wrong extension, but the error message is not removed after I pick a file with the proper extension.  I've experimented with `onfocusout` clauses, but with no luck.  FWIW, the other fields in the form are behaving properly (e.g., the message on a text field disappears after I enter a few characters into the field).  Is there a way to get the file field's message to clear after selecting a legal file?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `txt` and `doc` are file extensions, you want the `extension` rule.  The  `accept` rule  is only for Mime types.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method

Also, don't forget to include the `additional-methods.js` file.

---

**EDIT**:

> *"Is there a way to get the file field's message to clear after selecting a legal file?"*

Add a `change` event handler combined with [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) to force the plugin to run a validation test on the file field every time the value of this field changes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("form#testform").validate({
        rules: {
            file1: {
                required: true,
                extension: 'txt'
            }
        }
    });

    $('#file1').on('change', function() { // fires every time this field changes
        $(this).valid();                  // force a validation test on this field
    });

});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/9GcYj/42/

Comment: Hmm. First, oops / thanks for the accept/extension catch. But, after the change, it's still not doing what I would like; see http://jsfiddle.net/9GcYj/38 : (1) Click Browse and pick an illegal file, (2) Click Submit, get the validation error msg, (3) Click Browse again and pick a legal file, (4) old validation msg goes away (this is the part that's not happening).  Seems the old validation msg won't clear until a new Submit; onfocusout doesn't catch the file selection via Browse.  Is there some event I can trap to force a re-validation after file selection?  Or something?

Comment: @JimMiller, please note that when you use the `onfocusout` callback function, you've over-written the default `onfocusout` behavior.  In your jsFiddle, clicking `submit` is the only way to get the error message to clear.  However, using the default `onfocusout`, the error message clears exactly as expected, when the field loses focus:  http://jsfiddle.net/9GcYj/39/

Comment: @JimMiller, back to your original question.  No, there is no other event you can capture on this field when a file is selected.

Comment: Understood about my onfocusout; that was left over from an attempt to use console.log to see what's going on.  But, working with your jsfiddle -- I'm just not seeing what you're apparently seeing.  In Mac Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, if I choose an illegal file, hit Submit, and get the message, the only way I can get the message to clear after choosing a legal file is by clicking the Submit button. Nothing changes when I come out of the file dialog, or if I click into the background of the "result" pane, or click into and out of the textfield. How are you making the file field lose focus?

Comment: @JimMiller, I've edited my answer with a workaround to this issue.

Comment: THAT'S what I was looking for -- works great!  A minor note: changing the validation test call to `$("file1").valid()` will run the validation on just the file selection field, and so not nag the user with validation messages on fields that he hasn't gotten around to filling out yet.  But anyway, thanks.